# How to use Java 8 docs in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm having issues seeing API documentation for Java 8 in Eclipse. Here's an example of the problem I'm having

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

If I mouse over `Calendar` then I see all the correct documentation, however if I mouse over `getInstance()` I get a message saying

> Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be
>   found in the attached Javadoc.

I have the Javadoc location for rt.jar set to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/, I've also tried downloading a local copy of the docs and had the same problem. Changing the link to the Java 7 docs fixes the problem I'm having.

Eclipse seems to be using the wrong anchor style (not sure how else to word it) when looking for methods. When it looks for the `getInstance()` method, it checks http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(), but it should be checking

> Calendar.html#getInstance--

All brackets and commas seem to have been replaced by hyphens in the Java 8 doc links. I experienced this problem with Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler), 4.3 with the patches for Java 8, and now with 4.4 (Luna)

Is there a way to update Eclipse so that it properly displays the docs in the mouse over tooltips?

Comment: is your installed JRE pointing to jdk 8, I can see proper javadoc with eclipse and jdk 8

Comment: You could also attach the source instead of the docs to make Eclipse display the javadoc information. This does not really solve the problem of Eclipse searching the wrong path, but it will at least make Eclipse display the javadoc information.

Comment: set it to jdk8 instead and retry

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Setting the installed JRE to JDK 8 fixes your problem.

This can be done by going to

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE -> Edit -> Directory and selecting the JDK 8 installation folder
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I've set the Installed JRE path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0` and JavaDoc path of `rt.jar` to archive path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-8u5-apidocs.zip`, path within archive: "docs/api". Clicking `Validate` says that location is likely valid, but when I hover over `String.toLowerCase()` in my code, it does not find the JavaDoc even after restarting Eclipse. Same happens if I set the JavaDoc location to `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`.

Comment: Important: In order for this to work, you must remove the javadoc location from rt.jar. In other words, the javadoc is embedded in the JDK.

Comment: I remove jre and install JDK and set path to JDK, this works!

Comment: To make it clear, I tried this but left the previously defined JRE entry disabled and then the java doc still didn't work after adding an JDK entry. By removing the JRE entry, I forced Eclipse to switch over. This since existing project specfic entries were refering to the JRE entry so the did not get updated until I removed the JRE entry.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JRE -> Edit -> Directory (Specify the JDK directory (and not JRE))

Step 2: Click "Restore Defaults"

Step 3: Click OK

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.10, Eclipse Kepler using openjdk-8

Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Click on your java-8-openjdk > Edit

For /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:

set Source attachment to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip
```

set Javadoc location to:

```
file:/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-doc/api/
```

NOTE: If you don't already have the openjdk-8 java doc, install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-doc
```

and for the source:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

Comment: The others didn't work for me, but this one does. Using Ubuntu 14.10, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and OpenJDK-8

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I did set the installed JRE to be JDK8. Still wasn't working until I clicked "edit" on the jre (under 'Installed JREs') then then clicked "Restore Defaults". Then it started working... Looking at each jar in that list I see it sets "Source attachement" and not "Javadoc location". Seems to work.