# Configuring Eclipse with JavaDocs for standard Java libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've installed JDK 8 and Eclipse Kepler on a new PC then imported some old projects copied from an old PC (that had been using JDK 6 but that is probably not relevant).

I get errors which seem inappropriate. For example in a class that implements `Observer`, Eclipse says my `update` method *"must override a Superclass method."*

When I hover the mouse over Observer in `public class Foo implements Observer {`

Instead of Javadoc I get

```
java.util.Observer
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc 
      and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

Obviously I need to attach some Javadoc for all the Java standard library stuff.

Some Googling and reading of tutorials hasn't led me to an obvious solution.

How do I fix this in Eclipse for all projects/workspaces?

Comment: I used the answer to [this][1] post:



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642230/how-to-use-java-8-docs-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the javadoc location to the library itself not to the Project's javadoc location property.

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries expand the app.jar node and select the "Javadoc location" sub node and you will see the "Edit" button at the right of the library tree is available. Then click the "Edit" button and you can choose your javadoc in a jar file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a `app.jar` node but adding a Javadoc path (a path to a bunch of downloads docs for Java API) to `rt.jar` enabled the Javadoc hover pop-up/tooltip feature (sorry don't know it's proper name). Do I have to do this for each project individually?

Comment: yes as you are specifying this in particular project properties.