# Configuring Eclipse JavaDocs for Oracle jre8 system libraries (2)

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

This is a follow-up question to [Configuring Eclipse with JavaDocs for standard Java libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22686456/477035)

I have "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers", Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819

In Eclipse source text editor I get tooltip help for a standard class

[image]

but not for a constructor!

[image]

I have downloaded Oracle jre8 and the jre8 JavaDocs. Here's the project ...

[image]

And here's the config for rt.jar ...
[image]

And here's the content I expect to see in Eclipse but don't

[image]

Where have I gone wrong and How do I get Eclipse to show Javadoc for constructors etc.

Comment: May this help? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ka3ak's comment motivated me to try associating an older set of JavaDocs with rt.jar

[image]

Which had the desired effect

[image]

I surmise that there's some change to the JavaDoc output format between Java 7 and Java 8 that Eclipse has not yet caught up with.