# Add Java Docs in Eclipse working on OpenJDK

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, documentation

Happy day and thanks you,

I have XUbuntu 18.04.1 installed on my system. I'm want to code in Eclipse 2018.09 trying to add Java 11 docs (jdk-11.0.1_doc-all.zip) to it, but I fail.

The OpenJDK 11 (10.0.2) installation was with command `sudo apt install default-openjdk`, basically this would should be sufficient, but... The problem can be explained with four simple images: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI9jE.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APwrY.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq5Hg.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izPkO.png)

Any solution?

Comment: You need to install sources/docs as well: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-doc openjdk-11-source`

Comment: @Rad, I was looking for a way to use that package in Eclipse. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859019/8948381), but sources for source (`file:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/src.zip` in my case) Eclipse says that _The path '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/src.zip' does not exist._ and, efectivelly, my file manager tag it as _"src.zip" broken link_. Yes, I have installed openjdk-11-source... [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT0Yr.png)  an complementary image.

Comment: I found _src.zip_ file in `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip`, thanks you.